# Disable desktop in GNOME

Tags: gnome, desktop, nautilus

I need to lockdown an installation (the user can only use one program, but needs their own account and space for files, so the kiosk mode is not relevant).

And the last thing I need to do is disable the desktop, prevent any icons from showing up there and prevent the right click menu.

I have tried `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons false` but this has no effect.

(this is on CentOS 7, with nautilus and Gnome classic)